# How to resolve NFS Mount 'Error 1222' under Windows 10 Pro

Tags: windows, networking, mount, nfs

I'm running the latest version of 64-bit Windows 10 Pro on my desktop box, which I'll call the Client box. I have another box running the same OS (the Server box) which I use to share six full HDs containing my video and audio media for Kodi. Since Windows SMB has never, *ever* worked correctly for this purpose, I was advised to switch to NFS sharing, which I've completed a long time ago. I'm using the commercial tool "haneWIN NFS Server" to share all that, and it works perfectly for Kodi on all my Fire TVs and my Windows machines.

But there are times when I wish to make changes to some of the shared content from the server using the client box. I've installed the Microsoft NFS Client, ensured that the Workstation service is running (it's set to auto start), and entered the following from the standard CMD window...

```
mount -o anon \\192.168.1.103\cube6\Films Z:
```

But I always get: "Network Error - 1222", which means **"The network is not present or not started."**

How do I resolve this, please? I've tried to find a command like "NET START NFS", but I was unable to find anything (which could be I used poor search terms, of course).

Note that I'm aware that even when I get the mount to succeed, I will not have write access. But I've found instructions on how to enable write access once I can mount the share in read mode.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I needed to start the Client for NFS Service first. Until I found: [How to mount and access NFS exports...](http://lifeofageekadmin.com/mount-access-nfs-exports-windows-server-2012-r2/)

... none of the many pages I've read about using the Windows NFS client for mounting a share even mentioned that in passing, let alone making a point of it.  Sure, it's obvious in retrospect, but why not state this as a requirement?

Oh, well. Problem solved.